# androidTest execution fails with error message 'no emulators found' in android studio

Tags: android-espresso

I'm trying to run espresso tests on a hardware device (asus zen M2). My app is loading fine on the device but when I try to run the espresso test after build, execution fails with the message 'no emulators found' message. 'Run|Record Espresso Test' is also working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Was never able to make it work, now with my android studio updated to 4.1 and plugin updates things are hunky-dory now :)